# Adding a scrollbar to ui-grid overlays the bottom row

Tags: ui-grid

An application that I'm working on has a `ui-grid` on the page.  Recently, we added a horizontal scrollbar to the grid and also enabled "pinning" so that some of the columns could be frozen while the grid was scrolled horizontally.

One odd behavior that I've noticed is that the newly added scrollbar overlays the last row in the table.  Has anyone else ever experienced this and, if so, figured out how to stop it from happening?  I've tried everything I could think of (i.e. changing row height, dynamic sizing of the grid, etc) but nothing is working.  I'm hoping someone else has overcome this issue and can tell me how they did it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way to resolve this, but it's particular to how our grids are created.

All of our grids that have horizontal scrolling have the first three columns pinned.  I used the code below to see if the grid in question has the grid option for pinning.  If the grid is `scrollable`, I simply add 15 to the grid's height. This makes the grid bigger so that there's plenty of room for the scrollbar without it overlaying the bottom row.

```
var scrollbarOffset = 15;
var buffer = 5;
var gridHeight = ((rowCount > 0 ? rowCount : 1) * rowHeight) + footer + header + filter + buffer;
var scrollable= $.grep(element[0].attributes,
function (rn) {
                return rn.nodeName === "ui-grid-pinning";
              }).length > 0;

if (scrollable) {
    gridHeight = gridHeight + scrollbarOffset;
}
```